# How do I use a MIPS array to store data at specific places?

Tags: arrays, mips

I am looking to set up an array and then store integers in specific elements of the array. For example, I want to store the number 7 at the 21th element of the array and the number 9 at the 27th element. I have been trying to do this:

```
       .data
array: .space 100
```

And when I set the elements:

```
la $t0, array
addi $v1, $0, 7
sw $v1, 84($t0)
```

I used a 4-multiple offset because a word is being stored but I am not sure if the errors (Exception 4 and 5) are because I am trying to store a word in a byte array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine. I guess your problem is that `array` is not properly aligned.
Memory can always be thought as a byte array, but MIPS does not allow loading/saving a 32-bit word at an unaligned address (where unaligned means that the address is not multiple of 4).

Use directive `.align 2` before your `array` label.